# How many bytes would I require to store few seconds of fan controller PWM signal?

Tags: bitdepth

How many bytes would I require to store few seconds of fan controller PWM signal?

Such PWM is typically around 25Hz, so I think I need to sample it at 50Hz, right?

But what about the bit depth? Since it's a pulse wave (and such takes only values 0, 1 I believe) then 2 bits does suffice, right?

So is the computation then:

50 times per second * 2 bits per sample = 100 bits per second = 12.5 bytes per second of signal?

Comment: Can you please provide either a plot of the typical fan controller waveform, or a mathmematical expression of it.

Comment: @Fat32 Does this picture suffice? http://www.bearblain.com/Tach%20Signal%202.gif

Comment: @Fat32 However, the TACH signal is two pulses per 1 full rotation of the fan. So in that case in order to e.g. capture a fan at 2000 rpm one needs to be able to capture 4000 pulses per minute or around 66 pulses per second. So how much is one pulse?

Comment: 3 values fits in 2 bits, though your graph only shows 2 values, which fits in 1 bit

Comment: Perhaps the TACH signal is actually at a higher freq than the PWM control signal. Because of what I wrote in the 3rd comment.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer is: find the maximum frequency in the signal, and double that. In the case of PWM, call $T_p$ the duration of the shortest pulse possible. The signal bandwidth is in theory infinite, but in practice, frequencies above $10T_p$ will contain very little energy. So, you can safely sample the signal at $20T_p$ samples per second.

If you need better fidelity, then sample faster, accordingly.

Now, a PWM signal typically has only two amplitudes, so you can use one bit per sample, or $20T_p$ bits per second.

Comment: How are the maximum frequency and the shortest pulse possible related? I know that such PWM signal is specced to be around 25Hz (with small deviations possible). The adjustments occur merely on the pulse widths (i.e. duty cycle), not the frequency (i.e. amount of "full" pulses per second), I believe. However, the TACH signal might be different as I mention in the comments of the question.

Comment: @mavavilj What would be the largest frequency with non-negligible energy produced by the PWM signal? Look at the Fourier transform of a pulse: its bandwidth depends on the pulse width. So, if you know what is the narrowest pulse you'll see on your PWM signal, you can determine what is the largest frequency that will ever be present in the signal, and that in turn determines the required sampling rate.